# How to breakup a list of list in a given way in Python

Tags: python

Given a list of list of integers, task is to write a function which will output another list of list of integers. It's hard to tell the nature of the desired output in words, I am writing some examples:

```
# list with one element will be returned
>>> func([[1, 2, 3, 4]])
[[1, 2, 3, 4]]

>>> func([[1], [1, 2]])
[[1], [2]]

>>> func([[1, 2], [1]])
[[1], [2]]

>>> func([[1], [1, 2, 3]])
[[1], [2, 3]]

>>> func([[1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 4]])
[[1], [2, 3], [4]]

>>> func([[1, 2], [2, 3]])
[[1], [2], [3]]

>>> func([[1], [2], [1, 2, 3]]) 
[[1], [2], [3]]

>>> func([[1, 2], [1, 2, 3]])
[[1, 2], [3]]

>>> func([[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]])
[[1], [2], [3]]
```

(UPDATE) You can use the following preconditions:

1. Each inner list contains integers already sorted and there is no duplicate entry.
2. The outer list has no duplicate entry.

(UPDATE) As you asked, here's what I think I'm stuck with:

This is a problem on some optimization on a Directed Graph, with numbers as nodes and inner lists as starting points of edges (the outer list is the set of starting points of all edges). Now, you might ask, "How there be multiple start points to a single edge, which is shown in some test cases?"

This is what I am trying to do: for `func ([1, 2])` the node 1 & node 2 can be merged to a single node. The output `[1, 2]` shows that these two can be merged.

Now look at `func ([[1], [1, 2]])`. The 2nd inner list tries to merge node 1 & 2 together, but the 1st inner list says node 1 cannot be merged to anything. So, the output is `[[1], [2]]`, indicating that node 1 & node 2 are to be kept separated.

For `func ([[1], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]])`, node 1 is to be separated, but node 2 & 3 can be merged; so the output would be `[[1], [2, 3]]`

In case of `func ([[1, 2], [2, 3]])`, neither node 1 & 2 nor 2 & 3 can be merged as node 1 & 3 can be merged, so the expected result is `[[1], [2], [3]]`.

There is a list of integers also, which comprises of end points of vertices, each integer corresponds to each inner list. When elements of an inner list are merged to one, there remains only 1 edge. When they are separated, there are singleton lists, and elements from each of which is taken as starting points; the list of end points are updated accordingly.

I think it will help you to realize my needs.

Comment: Or maybe set subtraction of each element with its previous?

Comment: Do you need to deal with a case like `[[1,2],[2,3]]`, where the second list doesn't contain all of the elements from the first?

Comment: And what happens in a case like `func([1], [2], [1, 2, 3])`? Does that return `[[1], [2], [3]]` or `[[1], [2], [1, 3]]`?

Comment: @GWW There's nothing to do with frequency. Each inner list contains integers already sorted. No list has a duplicate entry. (I have updated the question.)

Comment: @RoadieRich In that case, nothing will be changed.

Comment: @DavidRobinson `func([1], [2], [1, 2, 3])` is not permitted, the passing parameter has to be a list.

Comment: @cmd This will not work. Because, the ordering of the inner lists has no effect on output.

Comment: @pushpen.paul: I meant to put `func([[1], [2], [1, 2, 3]])`

Comment: @pushpen.paul I was not suggesting a solution I was asking what the desired output is.  It is still not clear.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Oh! That is supposed to output `[[1], [2], [3]]`.

Comment: Hey, you changed the question when you added this: >>> func([[1,2], [2,3]]) -> [[1,2], [2,3]]. That wasn't there when I wrote my answer. My answer no longer works with that added.

Comment: @cmd How can I tell you? I am also searching for it :-). It is required for a program doing some optimization.

Comment: @Hammerite Yeah, friend. I am still working on the test cases. :-(

Comment: Can you describe what you want in words? And if ordering is important then I'm curious what you expect for >>> func([[1, 2, 3], [1]]).

Comment: @Sarien Ordering does not matter. It will output `[[1], [2, 3]` (same as `func ([[1], [1, 2, 3])`)

Comment: I think if you were able to concisely explain what the thing is supposed to do, you'd be well on the way to writing it down as Python code. There isn't really a question to answer here because you're unable to express what you want, and if you were able to do so, you'd already have coded it.

Comment: @Sarien Ordering does not matter for the output also. It would look: `[[1], [2, 3]]` (same as `func ([[1], [1, 2, 3])`). But, it does not really matter whether it is `[[1, 2], [3]]` or `[[3], [1, 2]]`, because I would write another function to reorder this. I told you, my friend, it's hard to explain in words.

Comment: @Hammerite You are right, I am still to find the precise problem. I'll add the original problem description.

Comment: It would help if you gave us the context you need this in. Maybe we can derive the rules from that. BTW this is really irritating because it contains duplicates: >>> func([[1,2], [2,3]]) -> [[1,2], [2,3]]

Comment: I know its hard to explain the desired output.  But its even harder to come up with a solution when you have no idea what you are wanting.  If you want good answers you can at least try and explain the problem.

Comment: @Sarien The problem relates to Graph Theory. Please allow me some time to write the original problem description.

Comment: @cmd I am working on it, kindly allow me some time.

Comment: @Hammerite There was a serious mistake in a test case of `func ([[1, 2], [2, 3]])`

Comment: @RoadieRich I am extremely sorry, `func([[1, 2], [2, 3]])` -> `[[1], [2], [3]]`

Comment: @pushpen.paul so, the problem can be written as "the result should contain each number that appears in the argument, split into lists such that each list is either a subset of, **or** is disjoint to **all** lists in the argument"?

Comment: @RoadieRich I think it is OK. :-)

Comment: @pushpen.paul I've edited [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16526424/1894317) with the updated solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This relies on the list of lists being sorted in ascending length (and the outputs needs sorting), but works with all provided input as of time of posting.

```
def removeFromList(elementsToRemove):
    def closure(list):
        for element in elementsToRemove:
            if list[0] != element:
                return
            else:
               list.pop(0)
    return closure

def func(listOfLists):
    result = []
    for i, thisList in enumerate(listOfLists):
        result.append(thisList)
        map(removeFromList(thisList), listOfLists[i+1:])
    return result
```

You can remove the closure using more for loops, but it looked too ugly, and too deeply nested.

Edit: based on updates, this is the naive solution to the actual problem:

```
from itertools import combinations

def isSubsetOrDisjointTo(listA, listB):
    return all(item in listB for item in listA) or all(item not in listB for item in listA)

def func(nodesToJoin):
    #flatten list, extracting duplicates
    allNodes = sorted(set(itertools.chain(*nodesToJoin)))

    result = []

    seen = set()

    for length in xrange(max(map(len, nodesToJoin)), 0, -1): 
        #start with longest possible, work to shortest
        for sublist in combinations(allNodes, length):
            if any(item in seen for item in sublist):
                #skip possible sublists with options we've already seen in the result
                continue

            if all(isSubsetOrDisjointTo(sublist, node) for node in nodesToJoin):
                result.append(sublist)
                seen.update(sublist)

    return result
```

There are probably a number of ways this can be optimised or improved.

Comment: I didn't know that function programming is also supported in python.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(L):
    r = [L[0]]
    for i in range(1, len(L)):
        r.append(list(set(L[i]) - set(L[i-1])))
    return r
```

Comment: The ordering of the inner lists does not matter. :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
def f (L):
    return [[l for l in L[i] if l not in sum(L[:i], [])] for i in range(len(L))]
```

Edit: The OP keeps changing what the test results are meant to be so I dunno, this gives the correct answers for all the tests that were there when I wrote it.