# How to copy a list which will not be changed in function call in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-lists

I was working on these functions (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525224/how-to-breakup-a-list-of-list-in-a-given-way-in-python)):

```
def removeFromList(elementsToRemove):
    def closure(list):
        for element in elementsToRemove:
            if list[0] != element:
                return
            else:
               list.pop(0)
    return closure

def func(listOfLists):
    result = []
    for i, thisList in enumerate(listOfLists):
        result.append(thisList)
        map(removeFromList(thisList), listOfLists[i+1:])
    return result
```

I have a list which I want to pass as argument,
but I want this list to remain intact. What I tried is:

```
my_list = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
print my_list
#[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]

copy_my_list = list (my_list)

#This also fails
#copy_my_list = my_list [:]

print id (my_list) == id (copy_my_list)
#False

print func (copy_my_list)
#[[1], [2], [3]]

print my_list
#[[1], [2], [3]]
```

But it does change my original list.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `copy.deepcopy`:

```
from copy import deepcopy
new_list = deepcopy([[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]])
```

Demo:

```
>>> lis = [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> new_lis = lis[:]                    # creates a shallow copy
>>> [id(x)==id(y) for x,y in zip(lis,new_lis)]
[True, True, True]                     #inner lists are still the same object

>>> new_lis1 = deepcopy(lis)           # create a deep copy
>>> [id(x)==id(y) for x,y in zip(lis,new_lis1)]
[False, False, False]                 #inner lists are now different object
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me why this thing was happening?

Comment: @pushpen.paul that's because `[:]` and `list()` only create a shallow copy of the list, and the inner lists are still the same object. And you can change them from either `my_list` or `new_list`.

Answer (score 3):

both with `list(my_list)` and `my_list[:]` you get a shallow copy of the list.

```
id(copy_my_list[0]) == id(my_list[0])
#  True
```

so use `copy.deepcopy` to avoid your problem:

```
copy_my_list = copy.deepcopy(my_list)
id(copy_my_list[0]) == id(my_list[0])
#  False
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a tuple.  `my_list = ([1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3])`

`my_list` is now immutable, and anytime you want a mutable copy you can just use `list(my_list)`

```
>>> my_list = ([1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3])
>>> def mutate(aList):
        aList.pop()
        return aList

>>> mutate(list(my_list))
[[1], [1, 2]]
>>> my_list
([1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3])
>>>
```

As someone has brought to my attention, this solution is not foolproof.  The tuple itself is not mutable, but it's elements are (if they are mutable objects - which lists are).

Comment: Funfact: the lists inside the tuple are still mutable anyway - because they are lists so this will not solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried it with the function func(listOfLists) of the question?

Comment: yes and, that function returns an identical list for me (as in the function didn't seem to do anything).  So I tried mutating the inner lists to be sure.

Comment: example def doo_stuff(thing): thing[0][0] = 'outch' please think of linebreaks and stuff and then trow ([1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]) into that function and see what happens.

Comment: Haha, are you trying to burn me?  You are correct @RouvenB., but I'm still not wrong in my answer based on the OP's function. I will edit my answer though.